# for every non null value the code resets values to null in correctly

Tags: java

In the following code I am reseting the setOriginatingNumber to null since , for every non null value,

```
if (config.getOriginPhoneNumber() != null) {
                PhoneNumber originphoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
                config.setOriginatingNumber(formatPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber));
}
```

it will reset to blank phone number . This can lead to multiple issues
This scenario exists only in when a user edits the existing phone number value and changes to alphanumeric.

**How to make sure that for every non null value of config.getOriginPhoneNumber() the code does set to blank phone no**

```
public SmsChannelConfig applyTo(
            final SmsChannelConfigRepository repository,
            final UserContext context, final ModuleRepository moduleRepository) {
        final SmsChannelConfig config;
        if (source == null) {
            config = new SmsChannelConfig(context);
        } else {
            config = source;
        }
        super.applyTo(repository, config);
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(getOriginatorType())
                && "Number".equals(getOriginatorType())) {
            PhoneNumber originphoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
            originphoneNumber.setNumber(getPhoneNumber());
            originphoneNumber.setCountryCode(getCountryCode());
            config.setOriginPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber);
            config.setOriginatingNumber(formatPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber));
            config.setOriginText(null);
        } else {
            config.setOriginText(getOriginator());
            if (config.getOriginPhoneNumber() != null) {
                PhoneNumber originphoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
                config.setOriginatingNumber(formatPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber));
            }
        }
        config.setOperator(getOperator());
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(getOperator())) {
            List<ExternalResource> resources = SmsChannelConfigUtil
                    .getSmsProviders(moduleRepository, context);
            for (ExternalResource resource : resources) {
                if (getOperator().equals(resource.getId().getResourceName())) {
                    config.setOperatorName(resource.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        config.setDescription(getDescription());
        config.setName(getName());
        if (repository.query().all().isEmpty()) {
            repository.setDefault(context.getOrganization(), config);
        }
        return config;
    }
```

**Reset the originphoneNumber value to null only when getOriginatorType() does not equal to "Number"  so that it does not create multiple issues**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you trying to do: reset phone number if the input is not null ?

Comment: what is the default value of `originPhoneNumber` when you create `new SmsChannelConfig(context)`?

Comment: @alfasin

if the phone no is present already and then it gets changes to alphanumeric value , then the phone number value needs to reset to blank , This scenario exists only in when a user edits the existing phone number value and changes to alphanumeric.

Comment: rephrase your question so that people can understand better. what do you mean by "for every non null value the code resets values to null in correctly" anyway..?

Comment: @ronan are you trying to validate phone numbers..? that is if the existing phone number is changed into an invalid phone number then it should be set to blank, is that what you are asking..?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia
private PhoneNumber originPhoneNumber;
 public class PhoneNumber {

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_CODE")
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String number;
 }

Comment: question edited for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (config.getOriginPhoneNumber() != null) {
                PhoneNumber originphoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
                config.setOriginatingNumber(formatPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber));
}
```

with:

```
if (config.getOriginPhoneNumber().matches("^.*[\\w+].*$") {
                PhoneNumber originphoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
                config.setOriginatingNumber(formatPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber));
}
```

to check if the phone number is alphanumeric. If what you want is to test for *characters-only* you should replace: `[\\w+]` with `[a-zA-Z]+`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `if` block:

```
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(getOriginatorType())
                && "Number".equals(getOriginatorType())) {
```

to this:

```
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(getOriginatorType()){
    if("Number".equals(getOriginatorType())){
            PhoneNumber originphoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
            originphoneNumber.setNumber(getPhoneNumber());
            originphoneNumber.setCountryCode(getCountryCode());
            config.setOriginPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber);
            config.setOriginatingNumber(formatPhoneNumber(originphoneNumber));
            config.setOriginText(null);
    } else {
            // RESET originphoneNumber value to null
    }
}
```